# Trim whitespace from esc_attr() in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am trying to figure out how I can:-

1. Remove all white-space; and
2. Remove all other characters e.g. ()

I have a phone number which is pulled from user profile and I wish to make this a clickable link.

OLD:

```
<div class="phone heading-font"><?php echo esc_attr($user_fields['phone']); ?></div>
```

NEW:

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo esc_attr($user_fields['phone']); ?>" class="phone heading-font"><?php echo esc_attr($user_fields['phone']); ?></a>
```

Problem is if user enters their number as (03) 1234 1234 it won't work unless I remove whitespace and the () area code fields.

I wasn't sure how I could use trim with esc_attr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like below:-

```
str_replace(array( '(', ')',' ' ), '', esc_attr($user_fields['phone']);
```

Like:-

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo str_replace(array( '(', ')',' ' ), '', esc_attr($user_fields['phone'])); ?>" class="phone heading-font"><?php echo esc_attr($user_fields['phone']); ?></a>
```

Example:- https://eval.in/753919

Comment: Thanks. Looks good to me. Sublime Text editor seems to be getting a format error. Something to do with the str_replace(). Any ideas? Is it missing a trailing )

Comment: Yeah was missing the ) on the end. Thanks

Comment: @Trent  yes one bracket is missing. I have added it in my solution now. check once again

Comment: Thanks for the help